# How to add a blending effect on the entire content without affecting the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add a blending effect for each time a new content loads after a link has been clicked?

I've looked though google and most of the websites offer code that just fades images or IE that works only for that and on the entire page. I just want the content to blend a bit when it loads to another page showing the next content after a link has been clicked from the menu.

I just need a light blend between each content . No fade in or out just blend.

Great answer @codedude !!!  Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yea, that's possible.

Comment: Please don't make us write your code.

Comment: What does a blending effect look like

Comment: Internet Explorer has page transitions.  They're meta tags. One of them is a dissolve.  It might be what you're looking for, but it's only for IE. http://www.boogiejack.com/transition_effects.html

Comment: First off, it helps to make your questions looks somewhat professional. Loose the extra exclamation points and question marks. Have you researched this at all with a quick Google search? What did you come up with? What have you tried so far? For us to help you, we like to see evidence of some effort on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("CONTENT TAG").css("display", "none");

$("CONTENT TAG").fadeIn(2000);

$("MENU LINK").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("CONTENT TAG").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
});
</script>
```

Just change "MENU LINK" to the id or class of your link element. Be sure to also include jQuery as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As far as I know this should work with all browsers...

Comment: is there a way to blend when a page loads to another?

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what you mean by blend.

Comment: like instead of the body fade in (black or any other background) using the full page instead.so it looks like the page itself fading into another page without the interuption of the body background loading.I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say.Because somehow with the body color black (or any other that suits the page) gives a dramatic change when it's fading in even if it lasts for a few seconds.

Comment: the content blending instead of the whole background as it seems maybe this is the issue :( , the website has header and black background and white content so if the whole page loads it includes the header and background ,I don't want these two loading again

Comment: what happens if you replace the body tags in the above javascript with some div that contains the content? I edited the code a bit to reflect that.

Comment: the effect would stop working, :( Still no solution plus the mozilla browser is making now problems it just goes blank and then the page pops out.I just need the content to fade in and out and nothing around it (background,header image)

Comment: one moment I'm looking in to it, I'll let you know :)

Comment: It works great I got enough now to mark your answer thank you so much for your help,I'm sorry I took too long to answer but with home tasks can't be at the pc all the time. Can I ask you one thing, I noticed in IE8 the effect works great but there is like a split second white flash that goes across the page, it's because of the scripts loading but what can I do to reduce this,please help!!

Comment: I'm not positive but this could be because you're loading the javascript last. Put it at the top of the page so it's the first thing to load in the head. Also you might try putting this directly in your css file: $("CONTENT TAG").css("display", "none"); like so:

Comment: CONTENT TAG { display:none;}

Answer (score 1):

Transitions can be specified using meta tags in the header section for example

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="revealTrans(Duration=**,Transition=?)">
```

Comment: When you say *Transitions*, you aren't talking about CSS transitions, right?

Comment: does this work with all browsers?